# Using attributes from one class into another

Tags: python

In python, I want to create a coordinate system with two classes in separate scripts; lines and points where point class is just x,y and z coordinates and line class then have two of these points as attributes. My problem is that I don't understand how to write line class so it understands it is points it is getting and how to retrieve for example x in a point in line class. Point class looks like this:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)
```

I am not certain how to write the line class but it looks something like this:

```
import point
import math
class line(point):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt((self.p2.x-self.p1.x)+(self.p2.y-self.p1.y))
```

Where I should then be able to create objects either like

```
line = line((1,2), (3,4,5))
```

or like

```
p1 = point.point(1,2)
p2 = point.point(3,4,5)
line = line(p1,p2)
```

I also want to be able to create functions like the one in line class and to retrieve coordinates in something like

```
line.p2.x
```

or

```
line.p2[0]
```

giving me (in this case) the output of 3. I also don't want point to be a subclass since there can be points not belonging to a line. Perhaps there is already a good answer to how to implement line class in such a way but I haven't found or understood it. Most examples is either about subclasses or separate classes which doesn't send or share some attributes. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For your `length` function you'll want to square those two differences before summing them and taking the square root.

Comment: A line is not a kind of point. Inheritance isn't appropriate here.

Comment: You want `line = Line(Point(1,2), Point(3,4,5))`. Note that using the same name as in `line = line(...)` would make `line` refer to this object instead of the class after this line. Respect the Python convention of using capitalized names for classes. As a side note, note that you forgot to square both terms in your `length` methods.

Comment: (1) A line isn't a kind of point so you shouldn't derive from point. (2) You can use "isinstance" to check if e. g. "p1" is of type point (or of a derived class) and handle "p1" accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: classes should be title capitalized, so that the proper names would be `Line` and `Point` - that make them easy to separate from plain variables.

As you've mentioned, inheriting from Point isn't the way to go - since a Line isn't a point. But you're almost there with your example:

```
from point import Point
import math

class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt((self.p2.x-self.p1.x)+(self.p2.y-self.p1.y))

Line(Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2))  # should work
```

You can also use Python 3.6+'s typing support to say that you expect Point objects:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1: Point, p2: Point):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, helped a lot to understand.

Answer (score 1):

A tuple is not a `point`, and `line.__init__` will not automatically know to make the conversion. While you *could* add logic to `line.__init__` to detect the type of argument, I would recommend separate functions for creating lines from `tuple`s and `point`s. Which you choose as the "canonical" argument is up to you. Here's an example using `point`.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1: point, p2: point):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    @classmethod
    def from_tuples(cls, p1, p2):
        return cls(point(*p1), point(*p2))

line1 = Line.from_tuples((1,2), (3,4,5))
p1 = point(1,2)
p2 = point(3,4,5)
line = Line(p1,p2)
```

Based on how you want to *use* `point`, I would recommend a `namedtuple`, and again leave the responsibility to pass the correct type of argument to the caller.

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')

p1 = Point(1.0, 2.0)  # p.x == p[0] == 1
```